# Installing Google recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, captcha

Included in [Magento documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-google-recaptcha.html) the following steps to install Google recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.x:

Install Module:

```
 composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0
```

Enable Module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable --all

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

For the first code `composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0`, I get this error message:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package msp/recaptcha in
>   a version matching 2.0.0

It seems I have to add something to it and the code as I enter is incomplete. If I use a shared hosting and I want to install the module on: mywebsite.com. What should the command line exactly be?

Comment: use `composer require msp/recaptcha` instead `composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0`

Comment: Thanks! But my SSH has the same credentials for all sites. When I enter the above-recommended code, will it install recaptch on all Magento installs and sites?

Comment: If you have multiple site in same magento installation then all site will get this feature at same time however you need to update google secret key for each website.

Comment: Thanks! Only one step is left. I need to enable the module on a specific website, what is the command line I have to run, I am trying this but it is not working: php /home/DataBaseName/MYDOMAIN.com/html/bin/magento module:enable --all

Comment: if you have have multile domain in same installation it will install for all however you can manage it from admin that for which site you need to enable it. If you have hosted each domain in your hosting in separate installation then go ahead and it will enable for only that domain hosted with that folder.

Comment: I host each domain in my hosting in a separate installation. When I use [composer require msp/recaptcha]. I miss one thing here, when I use this code, does it install it for all separate installations or for a specific website only? and if for a specific website only, how do I know which one is that?

Comment: Have a look at this link, please: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237240/error-message-after-trying-to-install-recaptcha2-0-0-on-magento-open-source-2-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81197/discussion-between-aman-alam-and-sam).