# Error message after trying to install recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, captcha

Included in [Magento documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-google-recaptcha.html) the following steps to install Google recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.x:

```
composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0
```

This code did not work, therefore, I tried the code below (based on the recommendation I received [from my other post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237236/installing-google-recaptcha2-0-0-on-magento-open-source-2-2-x?noredirect=1#comment330604_237236))

```
composer require msp/recaptcha
```

I encountered the following:

[image]

Comment: Please confirm that `vendor_path.php` file exists and writable for web server user  at `/chroot/home/magento directory/app/etc/vendor_path.php`

Comment: Thanks. I checked this and I can see that it is: rw-r--r-- and the permissions number is: 0644, should I change anything?

Comment: No, you don't need to update please check path in that file also confirm that webserver user has permission to read that file

Comment: The file includes this:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.2/app/etc/vendor_path.php

Comment: It is right path and is that readable for webserver user?